# Python - get number of columns from csv file

Tags: python

I'm trying to determine the number of columns that are present in a CSV file in python v2.6. This has to be in general, as in, for any input that I pass, I should be able to obtain the number of columns in the file.

Sample input file: `love hurt hit`

Other input files: `car speed beforeTune afterTune repair`

So far, what I have tried to do is read the file (with lots of rows), get the first row, and then count the number of words in the first row. Delimiter is `,`. I ran into a problem when I try to split `headings` based on the sample input, and next `len(headings)` gives me `14` which is wrong as it should give me 3. Any ideas? I am a beginner.

```
with open(filename1, 'r') as f1:

 csvlines = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')

 for lineNum, line in enumerate(csvlines):
      if lineNum == 0:
           #colCount = getColCount(line)
           headings = ','.join(line)           # gives me  `love, hurt, hit`
           print len(headings)                 # gives me 14; I need 3
      else:
           a.append(line[0])
           b.append(line[1])
           c.append(line[2])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`len("love, hurt, hit")` **is** 14 because it's a string.

The `len` you want is of `line`, which is a `list`:

```
print len(line)
```

This outputs the number of *columns*, rather than the number of *characters*

Comment: Well it's an easy one to make. Especially if you intended at some point to work with that joined string. It can be easy to forget which one gives you what you're looking for

Comment: Especially since `str` and `list` both give a `len`

Comment: Right. How can I extract all the columns for a csv file of an arbitrary number of columns? How would I create an arbitrary number of lists based on the column count to store all the values in the column?

Answer (score 0):

```
#  old school

import csv

c=0
field={}

with open('csvmsdos.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        field[c]=row
        print(field[c])
        c=c+1

row=len (field[0])
column=len(field)

csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
with open(filename1) as file:
    # for each row in a given file
    for row in file:
        # split that row into list elements
        # using comma (",") as a separator,
        # count the elements and print
        print(len(row.split(",")))
        # break out of the loop after
        # first iteration
        break
```